# Scala Nested Futures

Tags: scala, concurrent.futures

I have a couple of futures. campaignFuture returns a List[BigInt] and I want to be able to call the second future profileFuture for each of the values in the list returned from the first one. The second future can only be called when the first one is complete. How do I achieve this in Scala?

```
campaignFuture(1923).flatMap?? (May be?)

def campaignFuture(advertiserId: Int): Future[List[BigInt]] = Future {
  val campaignHttpResponse = getCampaigns(advertiserId.intValue())
  parseProfileIds(campaignHttpResponse.entity.asString)
}

def profileFuture(profileId: Int): Future[List[String]] = Future {
  val profileHttpResponse = getProfiles(profileId.intValue())
  parseSegmentNames(profileHttpResponse.entity.asString)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A for comprehension is here not applicable because we have a mix of List's and Future's.
So, your friends are map and flatMap:

## To react on Future result

```
  import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise, Await}
  import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def campaignFuture(advertiserId: Int): Future[List[BigInt]] = Future {
    List(1, 2, 3)
  }
  def profileFuture(profileId: Int): Future[List[String]] = {
    // delayed Future
    val p = Promise[List[String]]
    Future {
      val delay: Int = (math.random * 5).toInt
      Thread.sleep(delay * 1000)
      p.success(List(s"profile-for:$profileId", s"delayed:$delay sec"))
    }
    p.future
  }



  // Future[List[Future[List[String]]]
  val listOfProfileFuturesFuture = campaignFuture(1).map { campaign =>
    campaign.map(id => profileFuture(id.toInt))
  }

  // React on Futures which are done
  listOfProfileFuturesFuture foreach { campaignFutureRes =>
    campaignFutureRes.foreach { profileFutureRes =>
      profileFutureRes.foreach(profileListEntry => println(s"${new Date} done: $profileListEntry"))
    }
  }


  // !!ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSE - THIS CODE BLOCKS AND EXITS THE VM WHEN THE FUTURES ARE DONE!!
  println(s"${new Date} waiting for futures")
  listOfProfileFuturesFuture.foreach{listOfFut =>
    Await.ready(Future.sequence(listOfFut), Duration.Inf)
    println(s"${new Date} all futures done")
    System.exit(0)
  }
  scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
```

## To get the result of all Futures at once

```
  import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
  import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def campaignFuture(advertiserId: Int): Future[List[BigInt]] = Future {
    List(1, 2, 3)
  }
  def profileFuture(profileId: Int): Future[List[String]] = Future {
    List(s"profile-for:$profileId")
  }


  // type: Future[List[Future[List[String]]]]
  val listOfProfileFutures = campaignFuture(1).map { campaign =>
    campaign.map(id => profileFuture(id.toInt))
  }

  // type: Future[List[List[String]]]
  val listOfProfileFuture = listOfProfileFutures.flatMap(s => Future.sequence(s))


  // print the result
  //listOfProfileFuture.foreach(println)
  //scala.io.StdIn.readLine()

  // wait for the result (THIS BLOCKS INFINITY!)
  Await.result(listOfProfileFuture, Duration.Inf)
```

---

- we use [Future.sequence](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/2.11.x/api/2.11.xhttp://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@sequence[A,M[X]%3C:TraversableOnce[X]]%28in:M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]]%29%28implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]],A,M[A]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future[M[A]]) to convert a List[Future[T]] to Future[List[T]].
- [flatMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/2.11.x/api/2.11.x/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@flatMap[S]%28f:T=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[S]%29%28implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future[S]) to get a Future[T] from Future[Future[T]]
- if you need wait for the result (BLOCKING!) use [Await](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$) to wait for the result

Comment: This one works! But how do I capture the result from listOfProfileFuture? You don't have a control over when these futures will complete as such. The caller would have just created these futures and run them in the background. I would like to get the output from these futures. Please let me know.

Comment: If you want wait for the result, use Await.result(listOfProfileFuture, Duration.Inf)

Comment: Is there a way I can print it to a file as I start getting output from these futures? Doing a Await will block the current thread right?

Comment: yes, Await blocks. what do you mean with 'print it to a file'?

Comment: Write the output to a file as and when I get the output from the futures. The reason I ask this I would like to do some processing on these data.